# Accessing an attribute of an object owned by a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I do this:

```
current_user.predictions.inspect
```

I get this:

```
#<Prediction id: 1, home_prediction: 1, away_prediction: 2, first_goalscorer: "Baaaa", double: nil, user_id: 1, match_id: 1, created_at: "2013-12-04 22:48:23", updated_at: "2013-12-04 22:48:23">
```

But when I do this:

```
current_user.predictions.match_id
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `match_id'
```

How do I access the match_id of a user's prediction and ensure that they have not already made a prediction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something seems off there

current_user.predictions is plural so it sounds like a collection

so try:

```
current_user.predictions.first.match_id
```